# Is there any alternative to a @Autowired service in spring MVC in case the service is not managed by spring?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a layered application where the data access layer and business logic layer are plain Java projects, no Spring, I'd like to add a web front end to it using Spring MVC.

The problem I see is that since the business logic layer, that exposes CRUD operations is not managed by Spring, on a MVC controller I wouldn't be able to use the @Autowired annotation on the business logic class exposing the CRUD operations. As a alternative I can think of either adding the business logic class as a (static) class member or simply just a instance variable of the controller. I've tested both of these and it works, but I'm wondering what kind of implications this could bring and if there is another, better solution to this problem, that doesn't involving bringing the business logic project to Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a config class and define a method that returns the desired type of bean as the return type and annotate the method with @Bean annotation and scan that config class. Then in controller class you can use the @Autowired annotation.

Comment: Would this be applicable for multiple services? Say I will have multiple controllers that will require their corresponding services, by a config class do you mean a certain type of class(by this I mean a spring specific class that inherits from something in particular) or just a class I define? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Yes, once a bean has been created in configuration, then you can autowire that bean any number of controller.

Comment: Right,but I mean in a many to many relationship, many controllers will use many services, will I need to say, do many config classes, one for each unmanaged service?

Comment: No you need to create a single config class and declare all the beans in the single config class. Then autowire those beans in your classes whereever you require.

Comment: Thanks, it worked great!
For any other noob like me here's a example of what the config class would look like: https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html